# Is it possible to run Apex on other then database server?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle18c, oracle-apex-18.2, oracle-application-server

Is there anyway to run apex on application server while having database on another server. I meant to say that I want to make one database server in which oracle database will be installed and another application server on that apex will be installed?
Is there any possible way to do that?

I've tried it by connect through remote database and it is working but I had to install oracle database on both server.

Comment: What is driving such a question?

Comment: Someone asked me to do such things, since I was confused about it so I though it would be better to ask here.

Answer (score 3):

NO. APEX is a set of PL/SQL and SQL code that MUST execute in the Oracle database. You *could* run a smaller DB on the app server to host APEX apps  and host the customer data tables on a different server. But APEX *must* run in an Oracle DB. Period.

Comment: As Joe said, here's a link to [architecture](https://apex.oracle.com/en/platform/architecture)

Answer (score 1):

In sort NO !

Oracle Application Express (ApEx) Engine (ApEx vestion 2,3,4,5,18,19) is running only on Oracle Database server, But for best performance, it is strongly recommended to use Web Server on seperate server,

Application Server Options for ApEx

- Embedded PL/SQL Gateway (EPG)
- Oracle HTTP Server (OHS) Configuration
- **Oracle REST Data Services (ORDS)**

for further information please refer to Oracle ApEx Installaion Guide

and official site  https://apex.oracle.com/  regularly!